# How to get user's profile information from magento facebook extension?

Tags: magento-connect, third-party-module, facebook, social

i am using "facebook connect and like free" extension of Magento and it is working perfectly. My next task is to get gender and age of a user who is logged in through his/her facebook account so that i can use this information in my code. How can i obtain that information?
Thank You.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about third party extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can understand you are using Belvg_FacebookFree extension. The data from Facebook is fill in `app/code/community/Belvg/FacebookFree/Model/Customer.php` -> `public function prepareData()`. You can see what are the fields for gender and age here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user . Please keep in mind that Facebook returns and Magento uses different types for these fields so you have to make some kind of convert/parse.

Comment: I got gender of a user. But still unable to find the age.